# Table of contents: file ended while scanning use of \contentsline

Tags: table-of-contents

I tried to make a (very simple) table of contents, but for some reason, it doesn't work. Or rather, I have two versions of pdflatex, in one it works fine, in the other it fails with the following error:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \contentsline.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.7 \tableofcontents
```

the two versions are (as output by `pdflatex --version`):

The one that works:

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.1
Copyright 2019 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.01
```

and the one that fails

```
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022)
kpathsea version 6.3.4
Copyright 2022 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.03
```

The mwe is as simple as it gets:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\textbf{Appeandicies}}

\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

I am using hooks, which aren't available with the first version.
Can I somehow fix this? Or is there some kind of a workaround? Or did I miss something in the table of contents definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you share files with different TeX Live installations and one is as old as the first one, you should always delete the auxiliary files, like `*.aux`, `*.toc`, `*.lof`, `*.lof` etc. The problem is not the `pdftex` version, but the version of LaTeX. With LaTeX of TeX Live 2019 `\contentsline` has only 3 arguments:

```
\contentsline {section}{\textbf {Appeandicies}}{1}%
```

But with LaTeX of TeX Live 2022 it has 4:

```
\contentsline {section}{\textbf {Appeandicies}}{1}{}%
```

So if the `toc` file of a LaTeX run with the old LaTeX is read while a LaTeX run with new LaTeX, this can fail with exactly the shown error message while trying to read the fourth argument.

However, several other issues can happen, using TeX Live installations with different ages, because not only LaTeX versions would be different but several packages, too. And so the user interfaces of several packages (and even the LaTeX kernel) could have been changed. Sometimes you can do a rollback, to use old packages versions also with the new TeX Live distribution, e.g., for LaTeX you can use package `latexrelease` to do such a rollback. See the manuals of the used packages, whether rollbacks are available or not and how they can be used.

But surely rollbacks are not available for all packages. And even new versions of fonts could result in different line breaks and page breaks. Because of this I recommend to use the same LaTeX version and package versions everywhere. This is often possible using either an up-to-date vanilla TeX Live everywhere or a TeX Live portable.

Using the same versions should also answer your additional questions. I can not give further suggestions about ideas or workarounds for missing hooks, because I do not know the hooks you are using. Here I would at least need more information. Sometimes there are packages to provide additional hooks, e.g., `eso-pic`, `etoolbox`, `scrlfile`, `filehook` etc. Please ask new question with a suitable minimal working example, if you need further help.

Comment: Your answer worked for me! I added an additional empty argument to \contentsline and recompiled from scratch –– this caused the error to go away!