# Is there a limit of \ref-able labels in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

At the moment I am writing my masters thesis and I have a lot of plots being set as `addplot table` with a corresponding label. There labels are referenced later like `\ref{plt:foo}` which is working like a charm. However after ca 10 figures (with 2 tikzpictures containing 3--8 addplots each; around 5000 lines of data per plot) every reference to a label fails.

The error message is

```
Package tikz: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tmp/main-figure_crossref21" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'tmp/main-figure_crossref21' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'tmp/main-figure_crossref21.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
```

Looking into `main-figure_crossref21.log` gives nothing obvious (some "optimized away" pictures and stuff) but the last lines are

```
...
A tikzpicture has been optimized away. Use '/tikz/external/optimize=false' to disable this.
A tikzpicture has been optimized away. Use '/tikz/external/optimize=false' to disable this.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+cmtt on input line 1063.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmtt.fd
File: t1cmtt.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)) (/home/path/to/project/latex/main.bbl) (/home/path/to/project/latex/main.lof)
Runaway argument?
{figur 
! File ended while scanning use of \contentsline.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.213 \listoffigures
                     
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 37474 strings out of 483057
 927590 string characters out of 5962300
 1437728 words of memory out of 5000000
 51707 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 562479 words of font info for 107 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 59 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 76i,20n,129p,10153b,705s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The failure leads to killing ALL references as `\cite{}` ("reference xy not defined" or something similar), `\ac{}`-acronyms and so on...

Since the error vanishes as I reduce plots (yeah, not suitable) I have absolutely no idea what's happening there. MWE cannot be given for (hopefully) obvious reasons.

Is there a limit of references I am hitting? Too many labels (as I give nearly every `addplot` a label)

Any suggestions are highly appreciated since I hacked away a solution using `colorbox` wich is not so pleasing to the eye.

I am compiling via `latexmk` with `texlive 2019`.

Edit:
I am calling externalization as follows:

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tmp/]
```

My plotting structure is like this:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    % \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ylabel={$|s_{11}|$ in dB},
            legend entries = {
                    Meas. 4~wires,
                    Meas. 1~wire rem.,
                    Meas. 2~wires rem.,
                    Meas. 3~wires rem.,
                    CST 4~wires,
                    CST 1~wire rem.,
                    CST 2~wires rem.,
                    CST 3~wires rem.,
                },
            legend pos = outer north east,
            ]
            \addplot table [% Messung
                    skip first n = 4, %Zeilen mit !
                    x expr={\thisrowno{0}/pow(10,9)},
                    y expr={20*log10(abs(\thisrowno{1}))},
                    each nth point = 20,
                ]{../plots/4wire/4wire_messung.s2p};
            \label{plt:conn_test_4wire_messung-s11}
            \addplot table [% Messung
                    skip first n = 4, %Zeilen mit !
                    x expr={\thisrowno{0}/pow(10,9)},
                    y expr={20*log10(abs(\thisrowno{1}))},
                    each nth point = 20,
                ]{../plots/4wire/4wire_messung_1disconn.s2p};
            \label{plt:conn_test_4wire_messung_1disconn-s11}
            \addplot table [% Messung
                    skip first n = 4, %Zeilen mit !
                    x expr={\thisrowno{0}/pow(10,9)},
                    y expr={20*log10(abs(\thisrowno{1}))},
                    each nth point = 20,
                ]{../plots/4wire/4wire_messung_2disconn.s2p};
            \label{plt:conn_test_4wire_messung_2disconn-s11}
            \addplot table [% Messung
                    skip first n = 4, %Zeilen mit !
                    x expr={\thisrowno{0}/pow(10,9)},
                    y expr={20*log10(abs(\thisrowno{1}))},
                    each nth point = 20,
                ]{../plots/4wire/4wire_messung_3disconn.s2p};
            \label{plt:conn_test_4wire_messung_3disconn-s11}
            \addplot+ [blue, dashed] table [% cst
                    skip first n = 9, %Zeilen mit !
                    x expr={\thisrowno{0}/pow(10,3)},
                    y expr={20*log10(abs(\thisrowno{1}))},
                    each nth point = 20,
                ]{../plots/4wire/4wire.s2p};
            \label{plt:conn_test_4wire-s11}
            \addplot+ [red, dashed] table [% cst
                    skip first n = 9, %Zeilen mit !
                    x expr={\thisrowno{0}/pow(10,3)},
                    y expr={20*log10(abs(\thisrowno{1}))},
                    each nth point = 20,
                ]{../plots/4wire/4wire_removed1.s2p};
            \label{plt:conn_test_4wire_removed_upper1-s11}
            \addplot+ [green, dashed] table [% cst
                    skip first n = 9, %Zeilen mit !
                    x expr={\thisrowno{0}/pow(10,3)},
                    y expr={20*log10(abs(\thisrowno{1}))},
                    each nth point = 20,
                ]{../plots/4wire/4wire_removed12.s2p};
            \label{plt:conn_test_4wire_removed_upper2-s11}
            \addplot+ [brown,dashed] table [% cst
                    skip first n = 9, %Zeilen mit !
                    x expr={\thisrowno{0}/pow(10,3)},
                    y expr={20*log10(abs(\thisrowno{1}))},
                    each nth point = 20,
                ]{../plots/4wire/4wire_removed123.s2p};
            \label{plt:conn_test_4wire_removed_upper3-s11}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}\\
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ylabel={$|s_{21}|$ in dB},
            ]
            \addplot table [% Messung
                    skip first n = 4, %Zeilen mit !
                    x expr={\thisrowno{0}/pow(10,9)},
                    y expr={20*log10(abs(\thisrowno{3}))},
                    each nth point = 20,
                ]{../plots/4wire/4wire_messung.s2p};
            \label{plt:conn_test_4wire_messung-s21}
            \addplot table [% Messung
                    skip first n = 4, %Zeilen mit !
                    x expr={\thisrowno{0}/pow(10,9)},
                    y expr={20*log10(abs(\thisrowno{3}))},
                    each nth point = 20,
                ]{../plots/4wire/4wire_messung_1disconn.s2p};
            \label{plt:conn_test_4wire_messung_1disconn-s21}
            \addplot table [% Messung
                    skip first n = 4, %Zeilen mit !
                    x expr={\thisrowno{0}/pow(10,9)},
                    y expr={20*log10(abs(\thisrowno{3}))},
                    each nth point = 20,
                ]{../plots/4wire/4wire_messung_2disconn.s2p};
            \label{plt:conn_test_4wire_messung_2disconn-s21}
            \addplot table [% Messung
                    skip first n = 4, %Zeilen mit !
                    x expr={\thisrowno{0}/pow(10,9)},
                    y expr={20*log10(abs(\thisrowno{3}))},
                    each nth point = 20,
                ]{../plots/4wire/4wire_messung_3disconn.s2p};
            \label{plt:conn_test_4wire_messung_3disconn-s21}
            \addplot+ [blue, dashed] table [% cst
                    skip first n = 9, %Zeilen mit !
                    x expr={\thisrowno{0}/pow(10,3)},
                    y expr={20*log10(abs(\thisrowno{3}))},
                    each nth point = 20,
                ]{../plots/4wire/4wire.s2p};
            \label{plt:conn_test_4wire-s21}
            \addplot+ [red, dashed] table [% cst
                    skip first n = 9, %Zeilen mit !
                    x expr={\thisrowno{0}/pow(10,3)},
                    y expr={20*log10(abs(\thisrowno{3}))},
                    each nth point = 20,
                ]{../plots/4wire/4wire_removed1.s2p};
            \label{plt:conn_test_4wire_removed_upper1-s21}
            \addplot+ [green, dashed] table [% cst
                    skip first n = 9, %Zeilen mit !
                    x expr={\thisrowno{0}/pow(10,3)},
                    y expr={20*log10(abs(\thisrowno{3}))},
                    each nth point = 20,
                ]{../plots/4wire/4wire_removed12.s2p};
            \label{plt:conn_test_4wire_removed_upper2-s21}
            \addplot+ [brown,dashed] table [% cst
                    skip first n = 9, %Zeilen mit !
                    x expr={\thisrowno{0}/pow(10,3)},
                    y expr={20*log10(abs(\thisrowno{3}))},
                    each nth point = 20,
                ]{../plots/4wire/4wire_removed123.s2p};
            \label{plt:conn_test_4wire_removed_upper3-s21}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Development of S-parameters when individual wires are removed.}
    \label{fig:Development of S-parameters when individual wires are removed.}
\end{figure}%
```

This is one of the biggest plots and I am referring to it like `...the measurements are plotted as \ref{plt:measurement}...` Nothing special. The tables and refs render fine when they are alone. Even with my quick and dirty workaround the compilation fails when I compile everything from scratch. I have the results in a exra file but had to comment-out everything first, then "enabling" each subsub-/sub-/section one after another otherwise I get above error.

The `csv`-files (not used in above example but in other plots; 900 rows) are of structure:

```
Frequency,Z0,eef,A,B,C,D,s11,s12,s21,s22
100000000,,,0.9784651015246741,6.460455678011887,0.006551548389630869,0.9787513223661867,0.0986999630848132,0.9951172379609634,0.9951172379609632,0.0986999630848132
101000000,,,0.9780334254597032,6.524171046668524,0.006616175695209604,0.9783253958216227,0.09966409178663775,0.9950211398801257,0.9950211398801257,0.09966409178663775
102000000,,,0.9775975021899148,6.587859930990531,0.006680776180699639,0.9778952791406952,0.10062754040484774,0.9949241670157937,0.9949241670157934,0.10062754040484774
103000000,,,0.9771573331741967,6.651522071725684,0.006745349575226487,0.9774609737781141,0.10159030257544086,0.9948263217379353,0.9948263217379354,0.10159030257544084
104000000,,,0.9767129198863721,6.71515720971214,0.0068098956079507824,0.9770224812034832,0.10255237194952627,0.9947276064368206,0.9947276064368206,0.10255237194952624
105000000,,,0.9762642638151953,6.778765085879359,0.006874414008068732,0.9765798029012972,0.10351374219344249,0.9946280235229195,0.9946280235229197,0.10351374219344248
106000000,,,0.9758113664643523,6.8423454412490505,0.00693890450481256,0.9761329403709403,0.10447440698887366,0.994527575426807,0.9945275754268068,0.10447440698887367
107000000,,,0.9753542293524564,6.905898016936096,0.007003366827450945,0.9756818951266835,0.10543436003296486,0.9944262645990597,0.9944262645990597,0.10543436003296486
```

And the `s2p` (5000 rows) of the simulations:

```
! TOUCHSTONE file generated by CST MICROWAVE STUDIO
! Date and time: Sat Jan 14 13:57:53 2023
! Project name: microstrip_pad_gap_bond_real_2.cst
! Parameters = {gap=5; k=8; pad_length=10; pad_width=10; tcu=0.018; w=1.16; wire_diameter=0.025; x=40; y=30; z=0.508}
! Header version: 2018
! Port assignment regex: !\s*Touchstone port\s*([0-9]+)\s*=\s*(CST MWS port|CST DS port)\s*([0-9]+|Zmin|Zmax)\s*\(\"(.*)\"\)(\s*mode\s*([0-9]+))?.*
! Touchstone port assignment:
! Touchstone port 1 = CST MWS port 1 ("")
! Touchstone port 2 = CST MWS port 2 ("")
# MHz S MA R 50
100                      0.12657        -108.081         0.981231        -21.6064         0.981231        -21.6064         0.126434        -108.436
100.18                  0.126781        -108.123         0.981192        -21.6444         0.981192        -21.6444         0.126645        -108.478
100.36                  0.126992        -108.164         0.981154        -21.6824         0.981154        -21.6824         0.126855         -108.52
100.54                  0.127203        -108.205         0.981115        -21.7203         0.981115        -21.7203         0.127065        -108.562
100.72                  0.127413        -108.246         0.981077        -21.7583         0.981077        -21.7583         0.127275        -108.604
100.9                   0.127624        -108.288         0.981038        -21.7963         0.981038        -21.7963         0.127485        -108.646
101.08                  0.127834        -108.329         0.980999        -21.8342         0.980999        -21.8342         0.127695        -108.688
101.26                  0.128045         -108.37         0.980961        -21.8722         0.980961        -21.8722         0.127905         -108.73
101.44                  0.128255        -108.411         0.980922        -21.9102         0.980922        -21.9102         0.128114        -108.772
101.62                  0.128465        -108.452         0.980883        -21.9481         0.980883        -21.9481         0.128324        -108.813
101.8                   0.128675        -108.493         0.980844        -21.9861         0.980844        -21.9861         0.128534        -108.855
```

The measurements (4000 rows):

```
#  HZ   S   MA   R     50.00 
! Rohde & Schwarz ZVA24 4Ports - Version 3.80 - 1145.1110k26 SN: XXXXXX
! Date: 2023-01-06 20:27:04
! Measurements: S11 S21 S12 S22 
! 
 1.000000000000000E8     1.042029475688858E-1  -1.065290759914500E2   9.781079180953836E-1  -2.577991341302378E1   9.833367573549814E-1  -2.550748510445864E1   1.119836084512002E-1  -1.040159494348078E2  
 1.002250000000000E8     9.913413643943311E-2  -1.078523606796985E2   9.723187220081836E-1  -2.625287261486539E1   9.790884092236124E-1  -2.517769952149715E1   9.702258000494277E-2  -1.084480850132391E2  
 1.004500000000000E8     7.884381603637183E-2  -1.033567032389521E2   9.677251298298297E-1  -2.644118184862909E1   9.747371483274715E-1  -2.540446279043051E1   1.051840006981895E-1  -1.161306108110866E2  
 1.006750000000000E8     1.112784864653997E-1  -1.168384848575994E2   9.812457281607980E-1  -2.581751639316593E1   9.697304833192876E-1  -2.584846818395180E1   8.390351285484286E-2  -1.091107088233783E2  
 1.009000000000000E8     1.083061640588796E-1  -1.139758741599370E2   9.776448882188492E-1  -2.594429422353149E1   9.564279269220757E-1  -2.580014927777502E1   1.147685499220039E-1  -1.050939065548295E2  
 1.011250000000000E8     1.164683653386142E-1  -1.030790350305040E2   9.672446009846910E-1  -2.603953136179920E1   9.692821521588825E-1  -2.552557914269541E1   8.526255727189470E-2  -1.045689353836641E2  
 1.013500000000000E8     1.120399085932656E-1  -1.010069927415484E2   9.703988481342869E-1  -2.598370900371254E1   9.735475738797395E-1  -2.568862105556770E1   1.090040486659360E-1  -1.063560141793176E2  
 1.015750000000000E8     9.267321976921311E-2  -1.048955494015638E2   9.672554748430543E-1  -2.562241779342486E1   9.703290977933458E-1  -2.575654263544651E1   1.063881593124380E-1  -1.118908123041718E2  
 1.018000000000000E8     1.063792460400093E-1  -1.218170575906252E2   9.728681364682958E-1  -2.546736529964048E1   9.694839375618162E-1  -2.673580048879713E1   9.515887815495328E-2  -1.162585816405809E2
```

At the moment I have 18 references to plots like above and the 19-th will fail (probably even when referencing one label 19 times, not tested as compiling on my machine takes around 8+ minutes when everything is compiled from scratch (tables and some really simple tex-structures (just positions and fill black/hatch pattern))

When I only compile only the results some dozen references throw

```
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256
ocument}. ========
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tmp/main-figure_crossref242" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' ========
===== The last system call resulted in an EMPTY output file. Maybe it is part of \ref. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ========
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tmp/main-figure_crossref243" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' ========
===== The last system call resulted in an EMPTY output file. Maybe it is part of \ref. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ========
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tmp/main-figure_crossref244" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' ========
===== The last system call resulted in an EMPTY output file. Maybe it is part of \ref. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ========
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tmp/main-figure_crossref245" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' ========
===== The last system call resulted in an EMPTY output file. Maybe it is part of \ref. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ========
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tmp/main-figure_crossref246" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' ========
===== The last system call resulted in an EMPTY output file. Maybe it is part of \ref. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ========
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tmp/main-figure_crossref247" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' ========
===== The last system call resulted in an EMPTY output file. Maybe it is part of \ref. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ========
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tmp/main-figure_crossref248" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' ========
===== The last system call resulted in an EMPTY output file. Maybe it is part of \ref. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ========
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tmp/main-figure_crossref249" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' ========
===== The last system call resulted in an EMPTY output file. Maybe it is part of \ref. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ========
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tmp/main-figure_crossref250" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' ========
===== The last system call resulted in an EMPTY output file. Maybe it is part of \ref. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ========
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tmp/main-figure_crossref251" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' ========
===== The last system call resulted in an EMPTY output file. Maybe it is part of \ref. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ========
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tmp/main-figure_crossref252" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' ========
===== The last system call resulted in an EMPTY output file. Maybe it is part of \ref. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ========
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tmp/main-figure_crossref253" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' ========
===== The last system call resulted in an EMPTY output file. Maybe it is part of \ref. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ========
===== 'mode=convert with system call': InvokiThis is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
```

during the compiling process but at the end it compiles trough. Now I am stresstesting it with 9000 copies of a single ref (leading to 9000 little pictures and not a single one inserted 9000times) but have no results yet.

I've searched for the `return 256` error but found nothing tex related (using duckduckgo)

Edit2:
A compile is currently running but I have some results from the terminal output:

```
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref128' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref129' is This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256
up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref130' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref131' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref132' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref133' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref134' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref135' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref136' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref137' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref138' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref139' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref140' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref141' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref142' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref143' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref144' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref145' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref146' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref147' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref148' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref149' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref150' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref151' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref152' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref153' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref154' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref155' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref156' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref157' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref158' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref159' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref160' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref161' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref162' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref163' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref164' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref165' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref166' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref167' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref168' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref169' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref170' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref171' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref172' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref173' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref174' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref175' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref176' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image 'tmp/main-figure_crossref177' is up-to-date. ======
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tmp/main-figure_crossref178" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' ========
===== The last system call resulted in an EMPTY output file. Maybe it is part of \ref. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ========
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tmp/main-figure_crossref179" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' ========
===== The last system call resulted in an EMPTY output file. Maybe it is part of \ref. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ========
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tmp/main-figure_crossref180" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' ========
===== The last system call resulted in an EMPTY output file. Maybe it is part of \ref. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ======This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256
==
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tmp/main-figure_crossref181" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' ========
...
===== The last system call resulted in an EMPTY output file. Maybe it is part of \ref. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ========
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tmp/main-figure_crossref192" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' ========
===== The last system call resulted in an EMPTY output file. Maybe it is part of \ref. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ========
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shThis is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256
```

So 170 references worked fine and I get some errors of empty files (three messages at first, but then always chunks of 12 files (had to trim due to limitations of SE))

Comment: Searching around for the same error message, maybe try deleting auxiliary files? e.g. [Table of contents: file ended while scanning use of \contentsline - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665833/table-of-contents-file-ended-while-scanning-use-of-contentsline) (if this happens when you hit e.g. 21 plots regardless of what there are in the plot, a possibility is that there's a corrupted file named something like `main-figure_crossref21.aux`)

Comment: Could you post a few lines of code showing some addplot commands and some data lines? That may clarify the issue further. The number of references is limited (I think? not 100% sure) but from your description it fails after 10*2*8=160 references, this is lower than the limit for sure.

Comment: Also you didn't say what you do with those references (maybe link each plot to a table or something), but do you actually need each plot to have a (dynamic) reference?

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that the problem is with the first reference that no longer appears.  But without that code, there's not much we can diagnose.

Comment: Show an example with one or two small plots so that one doesn't have to guess what you mean by label and how you call the externalization.

Comment: if you have labels tikz probably reschedules the compilation, and that means you perhaps ran into this problem: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1127 (there it is hyperref that is affected, but it could also break the lof-file).

Comment: If you look at the aux file, you will find global macro definitions corresponding to the pgfcode needed to draw the legend entries (which are then used by \newlabel).  Relatively speaking, these things are huge.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am not using the hyperref package.

Comment: Do you indeed reference each `plt:conn_test_...` label? If yes, in what way (maybe there are smarter ways to generate the references without `\ref` and `\label` if the input is well-structured)? If no, is it difficult to determine which plots you will be referencing and which plots not?

Comment: @Marijn No, I do not reference each plot. After I set up one plot I copy/paste the `addplot+label` block so they are leftover (and in other plots Ive ofthen deleted the labels in the s21-plot, as I never refer to them. The external mode starts from scratch on every run, right? So some other plots (results of a genetic optimisation, 20000x3, but I am limiting their domain)

Comment: Then maybe you can remove _all_ labels, delete the aux files, and add only the labels that you actually use back into the code. Of course this is a workaround and not a solution, but it may be useful.

Comment: @Marijn how does this affect the number of `\ref{...}`? Is there a limited capacity used for everything tex-related and deleting unused labels frees up space for refs? As I edited in the OP I have referenced one specific label 9000 times and after around 3500 references I got the error, that the tex-capacity has been reached/exeeded. I got this message once yesterday when I was messing with the thesis (deadline had to be met). Ive discussed the issues with some coworkers and they said they never had this issues as they do not ref plots like I do as it is considered bad practice.

Comment: All labels, even unused ones, are written to the aux file and are read into memory from there so that _if_ there is a `\ref` this can be resolved. However, a specific label can be referenced as many times as needed, because the label takes up capacity but a `\ref` statement does not. I just tried myself with `\section{something}\label{somelabel}` followed by 10 thousand `\ref{somelabel}` statements and that runs fine.

Comment: In any case this means that reducing the number of `\label` statements can help to stay within the maximum capacity.